# If an struct initialized with null values takes up space

Tags: c, memory, struct

I am not too familiar with C, but I am wondering how structs are constructed in memory. Take for example [this struct](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm):

```
struct Books {
  char  title[50];
  char  author[50];
  char  subject[100];
  int   book_id;
};

int main() {
  struct Books Book1;
  struct Books Book2;
}
```

I'm wondering if you just initialize it like `struct Books Book1;`, if it will allocate memory for all the fields it has (`title`, `author`, etc.). If not, wondering what it does. I'm wondering how a programming language compiles a struct when the fields are null or not initialized.

If it is empty/blank/allocates no memory, then say you set it to this:

```
strcpy(Book1.title, "C Programming");
```

And then you unset it. Wondering if it clears the memory so it goes back to zero, or it keeps the memory allocated.

Comment: in general, memory stays however the program last set it, until the program sets it to something else

Comment: There are simple and complex answers.  In the simple case, a declaration reserves as much space as is necessary to store its contents.  In your example, these are declared as local variables, so a compiler would typically move the stack pointer to reserve enough stack space for storing the members.  That said, an optimizer is free to delay that reservation until the members are written, and if the optimizer is sophisticated enough to know when the members aren't needed anymore, it is free to release that reservation.  The answers below touch additional topics, such as 'global' and 'heap' alloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct Books Book1;` is a variable declaration, not an initialization. All variable declarations allocate memory for the variable, there's nothing different about `struct` declarations. The amount of memory allocated is `sizeof(struct Books)`.

If the variable is not initialized, it allocates memory, but the initial contents of the memory are implementation-dependent (unless it's a static variable, then it's as if every field were initialized to `0`).

Global variables are allocated when the program starts; since they're also static, they will get default zero initialization if there's no initializer provided.

Local variables are allocated when the function or block is entered, and the memory allocation stays until the function or block is exited.

Comment: One thing I would add is that memory allocations on the heap rather than the stack can be accessed out of their scope so long as you still have a reference to the heap allocation

Comment: @GovindParmar The question is about variable declarations and initializations, I don't think it's necessary to complicate it with dynamic allocations.